# Time since event calculations in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the below table. I want to count the number of days since the most recent acceptance. So, for example, user 1 accepted on multiple occasions but only one of them is the most recent. I want to do 2 things:

Mark a simple truth value indicating `mostRecent == TRUE/FALSE` and calculate the number of days from that acceptance to today's date.

```
  user  status_name invitationDate
  <fct> <fct>       <date>        
1 1     Accepted    2021-09-09    
2 1     Declined    2021-09-10    
3 1     Accepted    2021-09-30    
4 4     Accepted    2021-11-10    
5 1     Accepted    2021-11-22    
6 4     Declined    2021-11-29
```

I have included the code to recreate the table below.

```
df <- tribble(
  ~user, ~status_name, ~invitationDate,
  "1", "Declined", "2021-07-13",
  "4", "Declined", "2021-07-31",
  "1", "Accepted", "2021-09-09",
  "1", "Declined", "2021-09-10",
  "1", "Accepted", "2021-09-30",
  "4", "Accepted", "2021-11-10",
  "3", "Declined", "2021-11-12",
  "2", "Declined", "2021-11-18",
  "1", "Accepted", "2021-11-22",
  "4", "Declined", "2021-11-29"
) %>%
  mutate(
    user = as.factor(user),
    status_name = as.factor(status_name),
    invitationDate = as.Date(invitationDate, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
  ) %>%
  group_by(user) %>%
  mutate(cumsum = cumsum(status_name == "Accepted")) %>%
  filter(cumsum > 0) %>%
  select(-cumsum)
```

Answer (score 3):

We could create the logical index by subsetting the 'invitationDate' where the 'status_name' is `Accepted`, get the `max` and check with the `invitationDate`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(mostRecent = invitationDate %in%
     max(invitationDate[status_name == "Accepted"]),
   Diff = Sys.Date() - invitationDate[mostRecent]) %>%
  ungroup
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It works on a sample, but when I try this on the whole dataset I get the following error:

`Diff` must be size 290845 or 1, not 89.

290845 happens to be the number of observations in the dataset.

Comment: @I_like_insights I think you have some groups having no 'Accepted.  You can have a condition like `df %>% mutate(mostRecent = if("Accepted" %in% status_name) invitationDate %in%
     max(invitationDate[status_name == "Accepted"]) else FALSE, Diff = Sys.Date() - invitationDate[mostRecent][1]) %>% ungroup`